# Finding continuous line consisted of points surrounding points of different color

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry, graph-traversal

I have a problem with creating an algorithm that would find continuous line consised of points of one color (say blue) that surrounds points of different color (say red).

This problem occurs in "[Dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_(game))" game.

At first I tought that simple BFS would suffice (*I can treat two dimensional table of ints that represents map of points as an undirected mesh graph*), but unfortunately there's too many edge cases to take care of, like those showed [here](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kropki_(gra)#/media/File:Gra_w_kropki_niedozwolone.svg).

How can I approach this?
Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you state your problem more formally, or make it clearer by using pictures? I can't understand what your algorithm is supposed to do. Also, please make clear what is the *input* to the algorithm, and what is the desired *output*.

Comment: This line is actually a polygon? How do you store the dots? So you are interested only in non-intersecting case when at least one edge is surrounded by hull of another colour?

Comment: Sorry, I meant edges, anyway, it boils down to finding cycles which are not intersected by edges of the opposite colour and checking whether there are edges of the opposite colour inside? So the input is a matrix with edges after the game is finished, and the implicit goal is to calculate a score?

Comment: Yes, line forms polygon and the algorithm is fired every time a new point is placed, instead of doing it at the end of the game (this should simplify the case, correct me if Im wrong). The map is representet as 2d matrix, so map[y][x] is in fact (x, y) point. We can treat each point of the same color as the vertices of the same graph. Each vertex is connected by edge to another vertex if the distance between them equals 1 in all directions, also diagonally.

Comment: Please edit the question to include all relevant information in the question, and so the question reads well as a self-contained unit for someone who reads it for the first time.  We want the question to stand on its own, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Thank you!